# 22.04 Second GPU screens won’t show desktop

Tags: multiple-monitors

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my old Windows machine (not dual booting). I have two video cards and four monitors. When I did the installation, all four screens worked correctly. When it’s booting, all four screens work. The GTX 980 is working fine. The GT 730 is detected and the monitors have a signal, but the screens are black. I can move my mouse pointer onto those screens and the pointer icon looks fine, but nothing else will display on the screens. Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this problem, switch from Wayland to X11. To permanently do that:
Edit the /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file and uncomment WaylandEnable=false